How would you calculate the FWHM of a point spread function with 2 peaks, such as those present when differentiating a hysteresis loop curve?
To evaluate the spatial resolution of an imaging system, it is common to take the FWHM of a point spread function (PSF) describing said system. In my case, the imaging system is Magnetic Particle Imaging (MPI).
The literature I've found seems to love assuming that the magnetisation (M-H) curve is of superparamagnetic nature, although particle-particle interactions and high frequencies demonstrate hysteresis can take place.
By differentiating M-H curves with respect to H, one will obtain the PSF. For superparamagnetic/anhysteretic/Langevin curves, the PSF is a single peak. The corresponding FWHM value is thus fairly straightforward to calculate.
For M-H curves displaying hysteresis, however, I would obtain two peaks. What method should I approach to calculate the FWHM? In the few papers I've found that treat this problem, one [1] suggests treating the double peak as a fat single one:

Another one [3] I think suggests superpositioning both peaks into a single one, and then taking the FWHM of it:

In the paper, they say the FWHM values of S,M,L are 9.34, 6.57, and 6.49, respectively, which seems odd since the numbers don't really match the graph, unless I seriously misunderstood it.
Is there a correct way of calculating the FWHM? Or do people just go as they please since perhaps it's not that researched of an area yet? I've been searching for hours and any paper I haven't read on the topic is probably because I don't have access to it.
I should also say, many papers I found don't actually relate to magnetism specifically, and I don't know how relevant these can be. In this paper [5] for example, the FWHM is treated as in [1], but is it a good enough reason to follow this method?

Thank you in advance for any answers and suggestions!

Personally, I prefer to start with the goal, which I try to achieve, and then perform my analysis keeping this goal in mind. Your goal is probably not to state some FWHM number, but to use the imaging system to measure particles. Maybe for your case it is better to use a different resolution criterion: Not using FWHM, but Rayleigh's criterion.
